# sparkling lights in opengl es 2.0 android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to create something like a decoration light for my application. It should be a light which is very tiny but visible, just like the led light indicator in phones. I want it to have different colors like red, green etc.

I am new to opengl. I am aware of things like rendering objects with vertices, and providing texture to it. I also tried things like directional and ambient lights. But its only source of light. So I tried doing like a Sphere with with texture and having a light on it. But it didn't look natural.

I saw some websites with things like point sprites. I am not sure if this will be my solution. can some one give me a kind of solution to get a decoration light.

A sample code or a tutorial link will be very helpful. Also please let me know how to control the light color. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lights to colour the object if the object is a light itself.

If you're using opengl-es 2.0 then you must have some shaders. Start with a fixed colour shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 myColour;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = myColour;
}
```

Which will colour that object whatever the colour myColour is set to. And to set that colour look up how to set uniforms.

Then you want to think about how the edges should look, the above shader will have sharp edges, where as you need a slight glow effect or a blur probably. Which goes beyond my experience I'm afraid.

A great tool to try out shaders on the PC before putting on Android is Render Monkey http://developer.amd.com/archive/gpu/rendermonkey/pages/default.aspx it's free and has a lot of great examples which you might find useful.